# Convert UTF8String to NSString in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, utf-8, nsstring

I want to convert `UTF8String` i.e.`0x000060000292d290` to `NSString` i.e. `Hx5oE/NUb7kyUfofpeQwIr1LYcRUWQGOGnsgJqSEREI=`

In Objective C,
If I type `po [@"Hx5oE/NUb7kyUfofpeQwIr1LYcRUWQGOGnsgJqSEREI=" UTF8String]` on console then it gives me "0x000060000292d290".

How should I get reverse result?

Comment: That's a pointer (memory address), not the equivalent into `UTF8String`. But you can use NSString method `initWithUTF8String:`

Comment: `char *utf8 = [@"Hx5oE/NUb7kyUfofpeQwIr1LYcRUWQGOGnsgJqSEREI=" UTF8String]; NSLog(@"utf8: %s", utf8); NSString *reversed = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:utf8]; NSLog(@"Reversed: %@", reversed);` you might be suprised with the outputs...

Answer (score 1):

```
NSData *data = [[NSData dataWithBytes:@"0x000060000292d290" length:32] base64EncodedDataWithOptions:(NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength)];
NSString *numstr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    
NSLog(@"nonsens:%@",num);
```

:)

Comment: Super short: `@(pointerToUtf8String);` which also works with unichar like `"\u1234"`, important here is that char Strings have to end with `\0` null terminator.